# using nested structure pointers in C/C++ DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c, dll, marshalling

let say we have following code in a dll written in C-lang, where i try to map some functions defined in the dll as functionpointers, map to their actual functions, i follow following link to get till here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays

**Dlltest.h**

```cpp
typedef struct VersionInfo
{
  UINT uMajor;
  UINT uMinor;
  UINT uMRevision;
} STRUCT_VERSION_INFO;

typedef struct DllTestFPStruct
{
  int(*Close) (void);
  int(*Init) (STRUCT_VERSION_INFO *sVersInfo);
  int(*RegisterClient) (int id);
} STRUCT_DLL_TEST_FP_STRUCT;

typedef struct DllTestMgr
{
  STRUCT_DLL_TEST_FP_STRUCT *psItf;
  int iDummy;
} STRUCT_DLL_TEST_MGR;

extern "C"
{ __declspec(dllexport) void GetDllTestFP(STRUCT_DLL_TEST_MGR *psFP); }
```

**Dlltest.c**

```cpp
static int Close(void);
static int Init(STRUCT_VERSION_INFO *sVersInfo);
static int RegisterClient(int id);

STRUCT_DLL_TEST_FP_STRUCT sFP =
{
  &Close,
  &Init,
  &RegisterClient,
};

DLLTESTC_API void GetDllTestFP(STRUCT_DLL_TEST_MGR *psFP)
{ psFP->psItf = &sFP; }

static int Close(void)
{ printf("Closed called.\n"); }

static int Init(STRUCT_VERSION_INFO *sVersInfo)
{ printf("Init called.\n");}

static int RegisterClient(STRUCT_VERSION_INFO *sVersInfo)
{  printf("RegisterClient called.\n");}
```

Now i want to write a c# application which uses this DLL, specially it should make use of the "GetDllTestFP"-Function which maps the functionpointers to their actuall function. right now my C#-Application is as follow:

```cs
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int FP_DLL_TEST_CLOSE(ref VersionInfo sVersInfo);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int FP_DLL_TEST_INIT(ref VersionInfo sVersInfo);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int FP_DLL_TEST_RC(ref VersionInfo sVersInfo);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DllTestFPStruct
    {
        public FP_DLL_TEST_CLOSE Close;   
        public FP_DLL_TEST_INIT Init;
        public FP_DLL_TEST_RC RegisterClient;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DllTestMgr
    {
        public IntPtr psItf;
        public int iDummy;
    }

    [DllImport("DllTestC.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void GetDllTestFP(ref DllTestMgr ps);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VersionInfo vInfo = new VersionInfo();
        DllTestFPStruct dllFPs = new DllTestFPStruct();
        DllTestMgr dllTest = new DllTestMgr();
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(dllFPs));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(dllFPs, buffer, false);
        dllTest.psItf = buffer;
        GetDllTestFP(ref dllTest);  // Funtionpointers are not mapped, still null
        dllFPs.Close(ref vInfo);
  }
```

The problem is, that the functions do not get mapped to their actuall functions in the dll.
Any idea how can i achieve my goal?

Thanks

Comment: For C pointer you should use unsafe code

Comment: in addiction something like: unsafe {DllTestMgr* dllTest = new DllTestMgr();GetDllTestFP(dllTest); }https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/

Comment: The argument need to be declared as `[Out] ref DllTestMgr ps`.  The [Out] is crucial, it tells the pinvoke marshaller that it needs to convert back from the native to the managed struct after the call.

Comment: This memory layout looks like it matches a vtable.  However, the C# (really .NET) built-in support won't apply, because lack of `IUnknown` makes this not a COM object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# code is:

```
DllTestMgr dllTest = new DllTestMgr();
GetDllTestFP(ref dllTest);
DllTestFPStruct dllFPs = (DllTestFPStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(dllTest.psItf, typeof(DllTestFPStruct));

VersionInfo vInfo = new VersionInfo();
dllFPs.Close(ref vInfo);
```

You don't need to allocate `dllTest.psItf` becase in `GetDllTestFP` you do:

```
DLLTESTC_API void GetDllTestFP(STRUCT_DLL_TEST_MGR *psFP)
{
    psFP->psItf = &sFP;
}
```

So you copy the *address* of `sFP`.

Note that in general this is a bad idea, because you are giving to the "client" direct access to your data (the `sFP` struct). The alternative is that the client passes the memory (as you wrote before) and then you do:

```
(*psFP->psItf) = sFP;
```

(but then remember to free the allocated memory!)

Third alternative, the C-side allocates a block of memory through a shared allocator (one that can be used by C#, so no `malloc`/`new` here) and then the C# has to deallocate it.

**wrong solution is**

```
STRUCT_DLL_TEST_FP_STRUCT sFP2 = sFP;
psFP->psItf = &sFP2;
```

The lifetime of `sFP2` ends when the method returns. `psFP->psItf` is now pointing to a piece of stack that doesn't exist anymore. **don't do it!**

Ah... as written by @Hans Passant, depending on who allocates the memory, the `GetDllTestFP` can be `ref` or `out`. If the memory is allocated by C# then it must be `ref`, if it isn't allocated (as is now) or is allocated by C++, then `out` is ok and you'll save on the marshaling in one direction.